# Default value for a Relationship in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I created a model with two entities. Entity A has a relationship (to-one) to entity B. My problem is, that I have no idea how to set up a default value for the relationship. If I add a new entry to the entity A I get "no value" for the value of the relationship (action sent to the corresponding NSArrayControler or [newObjectEntityA initWithEntity:....] . What I'm missing is a way to assign a default value for relationships like for attributes.

Example:

```
Entity A
attrib a (has a default value)
attrib b (has a default value)
relation to B (has no default value)
```

Of course a workaround is something like this:

```
[newObjectEntityA setValue: defaultValueInEntityB forKey:@"relationToB"];
```

but I think there must be a more convenient solution.

Thanks in advance, 
Thomas

Answer (score 3):

You should override `awakeFromInsert` instead, this method is designed for adding in default values and other startup operations.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Factory, that creates new objects of A and preconfigure it according your needs.

Answer (score 0):

okay... I got the problem solved (more or less). What I did is to subclass the NSManagedObject and I overriden the method -(void) initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:

```
@implementation Locos 
static NSManagedObject *defaultType;

- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self=[super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    if(self==nil) 
    {
        [self release];
        return(nil);
    }

    if(defaultType==nil)
    {
        NSEntityDescription* locoType=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LocoType" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        if(locoType==nil) return(self);

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setEntity:locoType];
        NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Default==TRUE"];
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
        [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

        NSArray *array=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

        defaultType=[array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if(defaultType!=nil)
    {
        [self setPrimitiveValue: defaultType forKey:@"Type"];   
    }

    return(self);
}
@end
```

It sets the relationship "Type" in the entity "Locos" to the first record in the entity "LocoType" which has the attribute "Default" set to true. It works, but there is something I don't understand. I get a very strange effect if I simplify the method to:

```
@implementation Locos 

- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self=[super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

    if(self==nil) 
    {
        [self release];
        return(nil);
    }

    NSEntityDescription* locoType=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LocoType" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    if(locoType==nil) return(self);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:locoType];
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Default==TRUE"];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    NSArray *array=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    [self setPrimitiveValue: [array objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"Type"];   

    return(self);
}
@end
```

in this case, if I push a button which is bound to add: of an array controller (which is bound to the entity 'Locos') I always get TWO new entries! I run the debugger and the method initWithEntry is called only ONCE. I also get rid of the problem as soon as I remove the line

```
 [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

It also doesn't happen if the fetch is called only once as in the first code example where I store the record i the static variable.

Does anybody has any idea what happens there??

Comment: Awakefrominsert would be a better method to override, I think.

Comment: Hello jrturton! That's a ways better solution! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll put it as a very short answer then!